# how to sum array elements in flask python?

Tags: python

I am new in Python flask.
I want to sum all array elements using flask python.

I have the Following array in python.

`numbers =["2", "3", "5"]`

I Want to Sum all the array Elements, .and I want to have 10 as my result.

i tried this:

```
numbers = [2,3,5]
Sum = sum(numbers)
print(Sum)
```

However, it is not working. I Appreciate if anyone let me know. I don't know How to do it.

Comment: Try casting each item in element to int

Answer (score 2):

You cannot sum strings, you need to convert them to integers first:

```
numbers = ["2", "3", "5"]
s = sum(map(int, numbers))
print(s) # 10
```